# XSLT How to select files and remove some character from filename?

Tags: xml, file, xslt, text, trim

I'm wondering how can I remove/trim some character from filename in XSLT ,Infact I have to do some arithmetic process on my files and the key is the filename,but there are some files which have'text' before..
for example I have :
sdx.doc
sdx43.doc
textsdx.doc  ----> I want to trim text from file name and continue the process as -->  sdx.doc

substring-after(filename, 'text')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see what your XSLT code has to do with your question. If you have a filename such as:

```
<filename>textsdx.doc</filename>
```

use:

```
substring-after(filename, 'text')
```

to get:

```
"sdx.doc"
```

---

If you don't know which filenames to apply this to, select them by an expression such as:

```
filename[starts-with(., 'text')]
```

Comment: Thank you ,I've tried to resolve the problem but I couldn't,I put my codes  all together may help!

Comment: Your code still makes no sense to me. I suggest you post a small example of your input, and the expected output - see: [mcve].